# How to merge two rows in SSIS Excel SQL Command

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table in the middle of an excel sheet. The table is given below, here the header is defined in two rows so I need to capture both of them together.

For an example the header for the second column has to be Management JG8

[image]

For this purpose I'm using the SQL command option in SSIS and I executed the following query and the output is shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM [Monthly SSC Report$W7:AJ31]
```

The headers are not what I'm expecting, I require assistance in modifying the sql query to get the header by merging those two rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect your Excel file normally to the Source Data Flow
2. Your Source data should look like this:

[image]

3. In the Excel Source Editor, Rename the required columns. For Example:

[image]

4. To ignore the first row., add a conditional split that filters rows with Grand Total = NULL.

Comment: This approach seems better, but if I hard code like this I must ask the client to stick to the same column order.